# Unexpected Python Hex Escape Behavior

Tags: python-3.x

```bash
python -c "print('\xbe\xba\xfe\xca')" | xxd
```

returns

```
00000000: c2be c2ba c3be c38a 0a                   .........
```

Expected:

```
00000000: beba feca 0a                             .....
```

What am I missing?
I need to use this for the bof ctf in [pwnable.kr](https://pwnable.kr/play.php). I can use a combination of python and bash printf to get the required result, but I'd like to understand why this happens and how i can get around it.

Comment: On Windows, the expected is returned, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGAlx.png, My guess would be that some encoding is done (to UTF-8 ?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(You write `python`, but since Python 2 is EOL, and you tagged `python-3.x` I will write a Python 3 answer.)

`'\xbe'` is a string, containing the Unicode character U+00BE, or `¾`. When you `print` this, it gets encoded as a sequence of bytes according to your locale, which is apparently [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), so U+00BE becomes two bytes: C2, BE.

To output raw bytes, you should write a [bytes object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview) to a [binary file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout), for example

```
python3 -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\xbe\xba\xfe\xca')" | xxd
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, even better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

In the command `python -c "print('\xbe\xba\xfe\xca')"` , the string `'\xbe\xba\xfe\xca'` will be handled as sequence of bytes represented in hexadecimal form.

When this string is passed to the print function, it is first interpreted as a Unicode string, and then encoded as UTF-8 before being printed to the console.

To get the expected output of `beba feca 0a`, you can use the `echo` command with `-e` flag to enable interpretation of backslash escapes.

so

`echo -e '\xbe\xba\xfe\xca' | xxd   #result --> 00000000: beba feca 0a`

will do the trick for you.

Comment: or: `printf '\xbe\xba\xfe\xca' | xxd`, to just leave out python.